# Properties of Concave Function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

I´m working on completing and filling in the gaps on the solution manual of the textbook "Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics" by Stokey and Lucas.

I´m having trouble in chapter 4 with the following inequality the authors use.

We have that F: $\mathbb{R}^{l}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}^{l}_{+} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is concave and increasing in its first $l$ arguments. Take $\theta > 1$ and let $x$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^{l}$. They state that, by the concavity of $F$ the following inequality holds: $$ F(\theta^{t} x,0) \leq \theta^{t}F(x,0) $$ Where $t>0$. It seems like it's pretty obvious to the eye, but I can't find a way to prove it.

I even noticed that $3ln(1) > ln(3)$ which contradicts the former inequality.

I'm I wrong if I say that the inequality does not hold? Can someone help me prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that no non-negativity restrictions imposed on x and/or  t.

Comment: Sorry @Elizabeth . In fact, x and t are both non negative. I´m editting the question to make this clear.

Comment: How did you get that contradiction?

Comment: @ChinG they say it follows by concavity of F.